# Issues in implementing Windsor Castle at app config level

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have written a dummy program that implements Windsor castle below.But my problem is that i want to write its components in my WEB CONFIG but i don't able to know where to write what..can any one helps me in correcting that

Please correct me writing is App.config level of behaviour i.e to make it configurable???
Dummy Programm:

```
namespace NnjectFramework
{

    class Program
    {
#region  windsor castle
        interface IFoo
        {
            void test();
            void test2();
        }
        public class Foo: IFoo
        {
            private readonly string _arg1;
            private readonly string _arg2;

            public Foo(string arg1, string arg2)
            {
                _arg1 = arg1;
                _arg2 = arg2;
            }


            public void test()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Success method 1");
            }
            public void test2()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Success method 2");
            }
        }
        class Bar
        {
            private Foo bar;

            public Bar(Foo bar)
            {
                this.bar = bar;
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
            container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo>().LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient).Named("AFooNamedFoo"));

            IFoo foo = container.Resolve<Foo>("AFooNamedFoo", new { arg1 = "hello", arg2 = "world" });
            foo.test();
            foo.test2();
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        #endregion
        }

}
```

**What i have tried in App.config:**

```
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
  <components>

    <component id="uniqueId"
    service="Acme.Crm.Services.INotificationService, Acme.Crm"
    type="Acme.Crm.Services.EmailNotificationService, Acme.Crm"
    inspectionBehavior="all|declaredonly|none"
    lifestyle="transient"
    customLifestyleType="type that implements ILifestyleManager"
    componentActivatorType="type that implements IComponentActivator"
    initialPoolSize="2" maxPoolSize="6"></component>
  </components></configuration>
```

Comment: FWIW, configuring DI in XML is considered to be an antiquated approach. XML files are brittle and don't provide any compile-time feedback, which makes them difficult to maintain. The modern approach is to use a fluent API to register your types, which gives you immediate feedback via intellisense - it doesn't catch everything, but it is head and shoulders above configuring XML. You can always use Reflection to load types into your composition root from app.config if you need to make them configurable after deployment, but putting all of your configuration there is usually overkill.

Comment: already read that problems in implementation check here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113323/discussion-between-stylishcoder-and-bwa

Answer (score 2):

Dummy app (modyfied):

```
using System;
using Castle.Windsor;

namespace StackOwerflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        #region  windsor castle
        interface IFoo
        {
            void test();
            void test2();
        }
        public class Foo : IFoo
        {
            private readonly string _arg1;
            private readonly string _arg2;

            public Foo(string arg1, string arg2)
            {
                _arg1 = arg1;
                _arg2 = arg2;
            }


            public void test()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Success method 1");
            }
            public void test2()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("arg1: {0}. arg2: {1}", _arg1, _arg2);
            }
        }
        class Bar
        {
            private Foo foo;

            public Bar(Foo foo)
            {
                this.foo = foo;
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();            
            container.Install(Castle.Windsor.Installer.Configuration.FromAppConfig());            

            IFoo foo = container.Resolve<Foo>("AFooNamedFoo");
            foo.test();
            foo.test2();
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

And app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="castle"
        type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler, Castle.Windsor" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <castle>
    <components>
      <component
          id="AFooNamedFoo"
          service="StackOwerflow.Program+IFoo, StackOwerflow"
          type="StackOwerflow.Program+Foo, StackOwerflow"
          lifestyle="Transient">
        <parameters>
          <arg1>hello</arg1>
          <arg2>world</arg2>
        </parameters>
      </component>
    </components>
    </castle>

</configuration>
```

My assembly name is StackOwerflow, so you should modify it to your assembly name.

Comment: can you please do spoon feeding i my context i knew the parameters that i need to  use in component tag but i dont know how to relate it with my code..as i have mentioned above

Comment: @stylishCoder I improved my answer

Comment: Firstly thanks @BWA but i am getting error " Could not find section 'castle' in the configuration file associated with this domain."

Comment: using code :WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());
            container.Install(Castle.Windsor.Installer.Configuration.FromAppConfig());

Comment: @stylishCoder use my code. This works. `WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();`.

Comment: @stylishCoder Add in config like in my: `<configSections>
    <section name="castle"
        type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler, Castle.Windsor" />
  </configSections>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113323/discussion-between-stylishcoder-and-bwa).

Comment: got the issue..the startup tag must be placed after the ending tag of </castle>

Comment: @stylishCoder interesting, in my config startup is before castle and works. but i glad to hear that it works